# Parse datetime with hours 1-24 instead of 0-23

Tags: python

I have a data source that contains datetime's I'm reading in Python. The program always dies on the 24th hour, since python holds dates 0-23 not 1-24.

Considering I get a string like '2012/15/01 24', what is the best way to handle this?

I could use regular expressions to pull out the date convert that to a date time, then use regular expressions again to get the hour, convert to an int, subtract an hour then add the hours to the datetime, but that seems like a pain.

Is there a better way, or more common approach to this?

Comment: Are you sure that's an hour? It's a very weird system that stores hours 1-24

Comment: And if it is the hour, are you sure `24` doesn't refer to 0am the *next* day?

Comment: Normally, zero hours is midnight at the start of the day, while 2400 is midnight at the end of the day.  November 5th at 2400 hours is the same time as November 6th at 000 hours.

Comment: @MarkReed which would make some sense if the range was 0-24, but apparently it's 1-24 (so precludes the start of one day)

Comment: Yeah it's the electricity industry so everything is quoted in hour ending not hour beginning. So that 24 really represents hour beginning 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your data source actually has hours from 0 through 24 inclusive.  Check that.  It's a "dumb idea" to distinguish between midnight "at the start of a day" and midnight "at the end of a day".  If so, then as @Amadan said, 24 really means 00:00 the *next* day.

How to deal with it depends on the *exact* (exhaustive) details of how datetimes are represented in your data source.  One example isn't enough to nail that.  If that's all there is to it, then checking `thestring.endswith(" 24")` is sufficient to catch this case.  When you do have such a case, throw the 24 away, convert to a `datetime`, then add `timedelta(days=1)` to it.

Or if you're absolutely sure the hours range from 1 through 24 inclusive, you'll have to subtract one from the hour.  But I've certainly never seen a system that works that way.

Comment: The data source provides the dates as a string, in hour-ending format which is why it's 01-24 and not 00-23. But this works. Thanks!

Comment: Well, if 24 really means "sometime between 11pm and midnight", then of course it would be incorrect to add `timedelta(days=1)`.

Comment: In this case every hour is shifted to mean the end of the hour not the beginning. So I need to -1 hour from each to form hour beginning.

Comment: Yup, sounds right to me!  You don't need to muck with regexps, though - `thestring.rindex(' ')` will give the index of the last blank in the string, and then you can use simple slicing to split off the hour.  Or, easier, if you know there's only one span of blanks in the string, do `date, hour = thestring.split()`.

Answer (score 6):

Not mine, but it'll do the job.

```
try:
     time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, " %H:%M:%S.%f")
except ValueError:
     time = time.replace(' 24', ' 23')
     time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, " %H:%M:%S.%f")
     time += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just go for something simple like:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

s = '2012/15/01 24'
y, d, m, h = map(int, re.findall('\d+', s))
dt = datetime(y, m, d, h - 1)
# 2012-01-15 23:00:00
```