# Pandas: parsing 24:00 instead of 00:00

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset, in which the hour is recorded as `[0100:2400]`, instead of `[0000:2300]`

For example

```
pd.to_datetime('201704102300', format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

returns

```
Timestamp('2017-04-10 20:00:00')
```

But

```
pd.to_datetime('201704102400', format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

gives me the error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0

How can I fix this problem?

I can manually adjust the data, such as mentioned in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801783/parse-datetime-with-hours-1-24-instead-of-0-23), but I think pandas should have handled this case already?

UPDATE:

And how to do it in a scalable way for dataframe? For example, the data look like this
[image]

Comment: That's *not* a non-standard time format, but it's mostly ignored by programming languages and frameworks. That's 24-hour or military time, extensively used in *airlines*. If you buy airport slots, or calculate overnight charges, the last moment of one day is *not* the same as the first moment of the next

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pandas uses the system `strptime`, and so if you need something non-standard, you get to roll your own.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def my_to_datetime(date_str):
    if date_str[8:10] != '24':
        return pd.to_datetime(date_str, format='%Y%m%d%H%M')

    date_str = date_str[0:8] + '00' + date_str[10:]
    return pd.to_datetime(date_str, format='%Y%m%d%H%M') + \
           dt.timedelta(days=1)

print(my_to_datetime('201704102400'))
```

**Results:**

```
2017-04-11 00:00:00
```

**For a Column in a `pandas.DataFrame`:**

```
df['time'] = df.time.apply(my_to_datetime)
```

Comment: Also, I want to know how can I do it with the dataframe columns? See the update for example.

Answer (score 8):

Vectorized solution, which uses [pd.to_datetime(DataFrame)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method:

**Source DF**

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
           time
0  201704102400
1  201602282400
2  201704102359
```

**Solution**

```
In [28]: pat = '(?P<year>\d{4})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<hour>\d{2})(?P<minute>\d{2})'

In [29]: pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str.extract(pat, expand=True))
Out[29]:
0   2017-04-11 00:00:00
1   2016-02-29 00:00:00
2   2017-04-10 23:59:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Explanation:

```
In [30]: df['time'].str.extract(pat, expand=True)
Out[30]:
   year month day hour minute
0  2017    04  10   24     00
1  2016    02  28   24     00
2  2017    04  10   23     59
```

`pat` is the RegEx pattern argument in the [Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function

**UPDATE:** Timing

```
In [37]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [38]: df.shape
Out[38]: (30000, 1)

In [39]: %timeit df.time.apply(my_to_datetime)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.1 s per loop

In [40]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str.extract(pat, expand=True))
1 loop, best of 3: 475 ms per loop
```

Comment: What is the `pat`? is there any documentation on it?

Comment: @cqcn1991, i've added a short description to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Building on @MaxU's answer, some more efficiency can be gained by slicing the input string, parsing the date to datetime directly and adding the rest as timedelta. Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["201704102400", "201602282400","201704102359"]})

df['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str[:8], format='%Y%m%d') + 
              pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].str[8:10]+':'+df['time'].str[10:12]+':00'))

df['time']
0   2017-04-11 00:00:00
1   2016-02-29 00:00:00
2   2017-04-10 23:59:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Relative `%timeit` comparison for 30k elements df shows a comfortable **x2** improvement:

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str[:8], format='%Y%m%d') + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].str[8:10]+':'+df['time'].str[10:12]+':00')      
50 ms ± 270 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str.extract(pat, expand=True))
122 ms ± 1.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.time.apply(my_to_datetime)
3.34 s ± 3.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```