# converting "H:M:S" string in pandas to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
dictt={'s_time': ["06:30:00", "07:30:00","16:30:00"], 'f_time': ["10:30:00", "23:30:00","23:30:00"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dictt)
```

in this case i want to convert them times in to datetime object so i can later on use it for calculation or others.
when i command `df['s_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['s_time'],format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time`
it gives error:

> time data '24:00:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)

so i dont know how to fix this

Comment: If `24:00:00` causes your trouble, you should include it in the example ;-) Anyway, what time should that be, `00:00:00`?

Comment: related: [Pandas: parsing 24:00 instead of 00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43359479/10197418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### "24:00:00" means "00:00:00"

If it's just "24:00:00" that's causing trouble, you can replace the "24:" prefix with "00:":

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["06:30:24", "07:24:00", "24:00:00"]})
# replace prefix "24:" with "00:"
df['time'] = df['time'].str.replace('^24:', '00:', regex=True)
# now to_datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['time']
0   2021-04-17 06:30:24
1   2021-04-17 07:24:00
2   2021-04-17 00:00:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

#### 1 to 24 hour clock (instead of 0 to 23)

If however your time notation goes from 1 to 24 hours (instead of 0 to 23), you can parse string to timedelta, subtract one hour and then cast to datetime:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["06:30:24", "07:24:00", "24:00:00"]})
# to timedelta and subtract one hour
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time']) - pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
# to string and then datettime:
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str).str.split(' ').str[-1])

df['time']
0   2021-04-17 05:30:24
1   2021-04-17 06:24:00
2   2021-04-17 23:00:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note: the underlying assumption here is that the date is irrelevant. If there also is a date, see the related question I linked in the comments section.