# How to read 24:00 hour?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a csv file with 24:00 hour instead of 00:00 and try to read it with pandas. I found solution and try to adopt it. The problem is, I get an error and don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me?

My csv:

```
    Datetime            Value
45  01.01.2021 23:00    2.7     
46  01.01.2021 23:30    2.9     
47  01.01.2021 24:00    1.5     
48  02.01.2021 00:30    1.2     
49  02.01.2021 01:00    1.9     
50  02.01.2021 01:30    1.9
```

The code I got from the link above adopted to my case:

```
df['Datetime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'].str[:10], format='%d.%m.%Y') + 
              pd.to_timedelta(df['Datetime'].str[10:12]+':'+df['Datetime'].str[12:14]+':00'))
```

The error I get:

```
expecting hh:mm:ss format, received:  0:0::00
```

The link where I got the function to transform it:

[Pandas: parsing 24:00 instead of 00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359479/pandas-parsing-2400-instead-of-0000)

Comment: Don't just copy and paste, you'll have to adapt the code to your input format. Sorry if my answer to the linked question is misleading in that respect ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split()`+`pd.to_datetime()`+`pd.to_timedelta()`:

```
s=df['Datetime'].str.replace('.','-').str.split(expand=True)
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(s[0])+pd.to_timedelta(s[1]+':00')
```

OR

```
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'].str[:10], format='%d.%m.%Y')+pd.to_timedelta(df['Datetime'].str[10:]+':00')
```

output of `df`:

```
    Datetime                Value
45  2021-01-01 23:00:00     2.7
46  2021-01-01 23:30:00     2.9
47  2021-01-02 00:00:00     1.5
48  2021-02-01 00:30:00     1.2
49  2021-02-01 01:00:00     1.9
50  2021-02-01 01:30:00     1.9
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second solution is the one I take. Any idea why I got an error in my solution with the expected format?

Comment: @Gobrel `df['Datetime'].str[10:12]` and `df['Datetime'].str[12:14]` creating problem in your method because they are selecting only a single character so the corrected one are `df['Datetime'].str[10:13]` and `df['Datetime'].str[13:16]`

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace them like:

```
df['Datetime'] = np.where(df['Datetime'].str.contains('24:00'), pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'].str.replace('24:00', '00:00')) + pd.Timedelta(days=1), pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime']))
```